# How to get the percentages in Mysql when the data is repeating?

Tags: sql

I have a table which 2 column where the data is getting repeating. I want to find out the percentage of each row.

For example have a look at the below table

| job | final status |
| --- | --- |
| a | Success |
| b | Success |
| c | Success |
| a | Failed |
| b | Failed |
| c | Failed |
| a | Unknown |
| b | Unknown |
| c | Unknown |

(P.S: the data is like this but this is just for illustration purpose and not the actual data.)

now after the code I execution I want the output to be like the one mentioned below

| job | success % | failed % | unknown % |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 33.33 % | 33.33 % | 33.33 % |
| b | 33.33 % | 33.33 % | 33.33 % |
| c | 33.33 % | 33.33 % | 33.33 % |

Comment: You use three jobs and three statuses, so all percentages come down to 33.33%. Your example would have been clearer if you had stated whether the percentages add up horizontally or vertically. I assume horizontally.

Comment: Is it hive or mysql that you use? Please only use one product tag, not multiple conflicting ones!

Answer (score 0):

use 'CASE' and 'group by' for it:

```
SELECT job,
      CONCAT(ROUND(COUNT(CASE WHEN final_status = 'Success' THEN 1 END)/COUNT(*)*100, 2), '%') AS 'success %',
      CONCAT(ROUND(COUNT(CASE WHEN final_status = 'Failed' THEN 1 END)/COUNT(*)*100, 2), '%') AS 'failed %',
      CONCAT(ROUND(COUNT(CASE WHEN final_status = 'Unknown' THEN 1 END)/COUNT(*)*100, 2), '%') AS 'unknown %'
    FROM your_table_name
    GROUP BY job;
```

here is [FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/16cfcd8/3)

Comment: can you please help me with the code in HiveQL

Comment: @SaiSasidhar you asking about `Mysql` query, for `HiveQl` you need ask another question