# How do get the percentage in repeat rows?

Tags: hive

I have a table which 2 column where the data is getting repeating. I want to find out the percentage of each row.

For example have a look at the below table

| job | final status |
| --- | --- |
| a | Success |
| b | Success |
| c | Success |
| a | Failed |
| b | Failed |
| c | Failed |
| a | Unknown |
| b | Unknown |
| c | Unknown |

(P.S: the data is like this but this is just for illustration purpose and not the actual data.)

now after the code I execution I want the output to be like the one mentioned below

| job | success % | failed % | unknown % |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 33.33 % | 33.33 % | 33.33 % |
| b | 33.33 % | 33.33 % | 33.33 % |
| c | 33.33 % | 33.33 % | 33.33 % |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the percentages in Mysql when the data is repeating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76504654/how-to-get-the-percentages-in-mysql-when-the-data-is-repeating)

Comment: Should be obvious, but please do not post the same question multiple times

Answer (score 0):

You can use below SQL

```
select 
job,
100*sum(if(status='Success', 1,0)) / count(*) success_percent,
100*sum(if(status='Failed', 1,0)) / count(*) failed_percent,
100*sum(if(status='Unknown', 1,0)) / count(*) unknown_percent
from mytable
group by job
```

Here is an sample output for the SQL-
code

```
with mytable as (
select 'a' job, 'Success' status union all select 'b' job, 'Success' status union all 
select 'a' job, 'Failed' status union all select 'b' job, 'Unknown' status)

select 
job,
100*sum(if(status='Success', 1,0)) / count(*) success_percent,
100*sum(if(status='Failed', 1,0)) / count(*) failed_percent,
100*sum(if(status='Unknown', 1,0)) / count(*) Unknown_percent
from mytable
group by job
```

It picks up count of status and divide it by count of all records to get a %.

[image]